# Dojo's nested BorderContainer disappear in IE

Tags: cross-browser, dijit.layout

I have this terrible problem with IE 7/8/9.

I wrote an app using `Dojo toolkit 1.8.0` and `Play! framework`. It works fine in all browser except for IE. Its 'developers tools' show no error, so does firebug. The problematic code section is here:

```
<div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="design: 'headline'">
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="head" region="top">
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="menu" region="left">
        </div>
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" data-dojo-props="region: 'center'">
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="content_1" region="top">
            </div>
            <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="content_2" region="bottom">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div data-dojo-type="dijit.layout.ContentPane" id="foot" region="bottom">
    </div>
</div>
```

The result, in all browsers except for IE is like that:
[image: good way]

But in IE it is shown like that:
[image: bad way]

Can anyone explain why there are such differences? At first I thought that in IE content is hidden, so I set `overflow: auto`, but no scrollbar appeared after page load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my custom class added to `.menu` element:

```
.menu {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

This 2 styles broke my whole layout -.- When I removed it, it started to display properly.

Answer (score 0):

two possible reasons come to mind:

1. you don't have a 'center' element for the content container - afaik, the dojo spec requires one BorderContainerChild with `region="center"` or non region specified, which defaults to center
2. do you have any non-layout elements in your markup as direct child of BorderContainer? IE for once is more standard requiring and breaks on unclear markup in this cases

Comment: I had all regions properly set and only `ContentPane` as direct children of `BorderLayout`. The problem was with custom class added to `.menu` element.